# Is it possible to reject a Visual Studio git commit based on the message?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

We use the git plugin for visual studio, I'd like to set up a filter that rejects a commit if certain criteria aren't met (specifically if the commit message fails to find a regex match).

Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe use git hooks?

Comment: Have a look at the `commit-msg` Git hook: http://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: Awesome, thanks, I wasn't aware of these.  This is a good step towards finding an answer.